# Function abi::__cxa_current_exception_type() returns non-ASCII characters

Tags: c++, exception, name-mangling

I'm running into an issue where running on a remote machine (but not locally) results in an unexpected exception of unknown type. I attempted to get more diagnostic information by wrapping things with a `try {} catch {}` with a range of possible exception types (including `std::exception const &`) but the exception still falls through to the `catch(...)` clause.

For lack of a better option, I attempted to get the type of the exception with (the GCC/Clang specific function) `abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name()` (within the `catch(...)` block), but this results in an output with non-ASCII characters. (Specifically, I'm getting `0��m-` printed.) Attempting to pass it through `abi::__cxa_demangle()` before printing doesn't seem to help:

```
        try {
          // code which throws the exception
        } catch (std::exception const & e) {
          std::cout << "std::exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
        } catch (...) {
          int status = 0;
          std::cout << "__cxa_current_exception_type() reports error type as: " << abi::__cxa_demangle( abi::__cxa_current_exception_type()->name(),0,0,&status) << '\n';
        }
```

I'm a little surprised that the mangled name contains non-ASCII characters. (And to be explicit, we don't use non-ASCII identifiers in our code, and I'm not aware of any of our dependencies doing so.) I've also attempted to read through some [name mangling resources](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling) to figure out what might be going on with the `0��m-`, but I didn't find any likely reasons for the leading 0, or why there might be non-ASCII characters in the mangled name.

Do people have any ideas as to what might be going on here, and what sort of exception type is being thrown here? Or alternatively, are there approaches I may have missed to figure out the type?

Comment: Please show your actual code.  Are you, by chance, trying to access the `name` string outside of the `catch` block?

Comment: Is there a particular bit of code you want to see? I can hardly post the full 3M+ lines of code for the project in question block. I'd love to reduce things to trivial slideware, but the whole "running on a remote machine (but not locally)" thing puts a damper on it.

Comment: @R.M. it's a tough spot you're in - I can see that.  But understand that you are asking us to make guesses.  That's not a good format for what Stack Overflow strives to be.

Comment: @R.M. "*Is there a particular bit of code you want to see?*" - your `catch` handler that is reporting garbage strings.

Comment: @DrewDormann To be explicit, I'm not looking for "fix my codez". What I'm looking for is for someone with experience with __cxa_current_exception_type() and name mangling to provide insight into under which sort of situations the name reported by __cxa_current_exception_type() might contain non-ASCII characters (particularly ones of the form `0...`) and/or to provide alternative approaches to determine what that exception type is in the cases where said name is reporting non-ASCII characters. I was under the (mistaken?) impression that sort of specialized knowledge question was SO's remit.